# Responding to multiple mouse clicks to produce a different output - Tkinter

Tags: button, tkinter

I'm working on a problem requiring me to create a GUI (in  Tkinter) which shows a different word in the label (referencing from a list) each time the button is pressed.

I've tried researching and have found similar problems but haven't found a working solution yet. I have tried 'for each' and 'while' loops, and 'if' statements, but haven't been able to get the code working correctly.

```
the_window.counter = 0

if the_window.counter == 0:
    top_label['text'] = words [0]
    the_window.counter + 1
elif the_window.counter == 1:
    top_label['text'] = words [1]
    the_window.counter + 1
```

the code shown above produces the first word in the list only, and multiple clicks don't have any effect. does anyone have any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: move the counter outside the loop - you are resetting it to 0 every time.

Comment: how would it be counting the number of clicks? apologies as i am still a beginner

Comment: I assume you already know how to bind to mouse clicks. If you didn't, you can read it up [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm). But since you mentioned a button, you can just pass a command to the button instead to go through your list and change the label.

Answer (score 0):

You need need to keep a global counter, and update it each time it is clicked.

The following code illustrates the technique:

```
# initialized to -1, so that the first time it is called
# it gets set to zero
the_window_counter = -1

def handle_click():
    global the_window_counter
    the_window_counter += 1
    try:
        top_label.configure(text=words[the_window_counter])
    except IndexError:
        top_label.configure(text="no more words")
```